# What do Professions do for a Hunter?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, hunter-the-vigil

I've been reading about Professions in the Hunter book, and I don't get it? what do these really do for them? are they the fundamental equivalents of a "Clan" (in vampire)? does it give any convey special abilities? Seems to maybe give some additional specialties?

Comment: Some useful information can be found in these discussions: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35793/how-do-free-contacts-from-professional-training-work and http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35792/what-do-asset-skills-actually-do-in-hunter-the-vigil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're pretty straightforward. (p.56)

> All hunters have a Profession. In many cases, this is a specific job title (Soldier, Clergyman, Technician), while in others, it describes his primary activity or interest focus, regardless of whether this is an actual “job” or not (Socialite, Criminal,
>   Vagrant). Check out the Professions detailed on pp. 74-93 and
>   determine which best suits your character concept.
>   Each Profession has two Asset Skills, which represent
>   training or areas of expertise that are particularly pertinent
>   to that Profession. After choosing a Profession for your character,
>   look at the Asset Skills listed for that Profession and
>   choose a free Skill Specialty in one of them. (This will bring
>   your character’s total starting Skill Specialties as to four.)

So, an additional starting specialty and access to Merits like Professional Training and the like. They're meant to be a way of providing specialization and niches for Tier 1 characters who don't have access to superhuman powers or resources.

Professional Training gives you (at low ranks) free Contacts and more Specialties, reflecting someone who is "good at his/her job" more than simply high levels of skill might impart. It's an incentive to have characters with background and continuing lives.

Comment: let's say I have a Hacker with 2 dots' in professional training, that would potentially add what? specialty in cryptography, and programming (for free with the dots) and contacts in hacker groups(luzlsec, anonymous) and in "user groups"? for example?

Comment: @xenoterracide You've basically got it, yeah — Professional Training gives you (at low ranks) free Contacts and more Specialties, reflecting someone who is "good at his/her job" more than simply high levels of skill might impart. It's an incentive to have characters with background and continuing lives.